# How can we copy-paste text and image both from clipboard in uwp C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to paste a note with the combination of text and image in my chat compose box in the same sequence.
I am using dataPackageView to check clipboard content

For Example - I need to copy paste a note from a Microsoft note

[image]

```
DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
{         
  var img = await dataPackageView.GetBitmapAsync();
}
else if(dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text)
{                 
  string text = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
}
```

Comment: If the contents contains text and images at the same time, it's more than likely being stored as HTML, not as a bitmap and certainly not just as text.

Comment: yes. So how can I fetch that data? Do you have any example

Comment: `await dataPackageView.GetHtmlFormatAsync()`? Or `GetRtfAsync()`?

Comment: Yes. I am using GetHtmlFormatAsync but how do I extract text and image separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have copied a note(image+text) to Clipboard, then I checked the format of the content with [DataPackageView.Contains()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview.contains?view=winrt-20348) method, I can’t find any format to correspond it.

So you need to create a html string contains the text and the image, then use [Clipboard.SetContent(DataPackage)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard.setcontent?view=winrt-20348) method to add content to Clipboard with specified html format, then you could use [DataPackageView.GetHtmlFormatAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview.gethtmlformatasync?view=winrt-20348) method to get content, finally you could use webView control to show its content. Please refer to [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/main/Samples/Clipboard/cs/CopyText.xaml.cs) to know the detailed code.

Comment: I am copying data from the clipboard. So how can I set content??

Comment: Hi, I am facing a problem while copying text + image clipboard content in the sample code itself. Could you please help? resMap.Count is 0 even if the content having multiple images

Comment: Did you add the image file to Assets folder? There are two string type variable **htmlFragment** and **imgSrc** in the sample, htmlFragment is html string, it contains text and an image whose id is **scenario1LocalImage**.  E.g:( `<img id=\"scenario1LocalImage\" src=\""+ imgSrc+ "\" />`).

Comment: The imgSrc variable in the HTML string represents the image file location, the official sample stores the image file to Assets folder, then access it with `"ms-appx-web:///Assets/filename.png"`. Therefore, you also need to place the image file in the Assets folder.

Comment: But I am copying content from OneNote. This sample works if we copy data from sample itself